# Detect parallel lines using Hough transform in matlab

Tags: matlab, line, hough-transform

Suppose there is a binary image of a black background and white lines "plotted" on it, i.e., they aren't burnt onto the image. For example:

[image]

I need to retain only the lines that are parallel to atleast one of the other lines in the picture. If not perfectly parallel, at least close enough to be parallel(perhaps a variable that can control the degree of parallelism would help with that). In other words, if I choose a particular line and it has one or more lines that are parallel to it, I retain it, else I discard it. I need to do that for all lines in the image.

I came across [Hough transform](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html) but I'm having trouble understanding how to use the bins to check the orientations and determine parallel lines. Or is there a better way to go about this?

Also, since the lines aren't a part of the image and are just plotted on it, I don't have an image to feed into the Hough Transform function. Can I use the output of the plot function as input directly? This is the code I wrote to plot the white lines:

`Location1` is a m-by-2 matrix that contains the coordinates to draw the lines.

```
figure; imshow(blackImage); 
hold on ;
for i=1:size(Location1,1)-1
   h = plot([Location1(i,1) Location1(i+1,1)], [Location1(i,2) Location1(i+1,2)]) ;
   set(h,'linewidth', .1, 'color', 'b') ;
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why aren't you using `[H,theta,rho] = hough(BW);` then you have theta...

Comment: The thing is, I don't have an image. I have plotted the lines using the "plot" function and the lines are just overlaid on the image. I should have mentioned it in the question, apologies. Is there any way I can send the plot into the Hough transform function directly?

Comment: please edit the question, give all the details\code you have. If you used plot then you have an image, you just dont know it yet.

Comment: @bla I edited the question to include the details of the code.

Comment: Since you have the parameters of the lines already, Hough is pointless. All it does is find parameters of lines in an image. Use your `Location1` array to find parallel lines.

Comment: Are you sure that the code you posted creates the image you show? It seems to me that you are `plot`ting a single point in every loop iteration, not lines.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Sorry, I edited the code, it works now. Could you tell me how to use the Location 1 array to find parallel lines? By using the slope of the lines? Also, why won't Hough work, wouldn't it be easier to find the theta values and compare?

Comment: just use geometry .... `theta=  atan2(Y,X)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that

```
for i=1:size(Location1,1)-1
   % one line = Location1(i,:) to Location1(i+1,:)
end
```

then

```
theta = atan2(diff(Location1(:,2)),diff(Location1(:,1)));
```

But since lines are parallel even if their `theta` is in the opposite direction, you want to map all angles to half a circle:

```
theta = mod(theta,pi/2);
```

Now `theta` is in the range [-π/2,π/2].

To find similar angles:

```
[s,i] = sort(theta);
k = find(diff(s)<0.01); % diff(s) is always positive because s is sorted
i = i([k,k+1]);
theta(i) % <-- sets of similar angles
% Location1(i,:),Location1(i+1,:) <- corresponding lines
```